# How to show submenu bar on sidebar when mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to show submenu bar on sidebar when mouse over and close when mouse leave?  can anyone help me to solve this problem? I am newbie on using jquery.

JS CODE not working

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'200px'},500);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'35px'},500);
    }).trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation" style="border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
   <ul class="nav">
     <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1">Setting <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav collapse" id="sub1" style="font-weight:bold">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Add Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Update User</a></li>
        </ul
     </li>

     <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub2"><strong style="font-size:14px; color:#FFCC33;">Documents in Process</strong></a>
        <ul class="nav collapse" id="sub2" style="font-weight:bold">
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Incoming Products</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Document Validation</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be achieved with pure css transitions, no need for js

Comment: can you help me for this? I'm not that familiar when using CSS

Comment: You don't have an element with `id="nav"`, if you mean class use `.nav` instead.

Comment: I change already and still not working..

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.nav{
    width:35px;
    -webkit-transition:width 500ms ease-out;
    transition:width 500ms ease-out;
}
.nav:hover{
    width:200px;
}
```

> [see css transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)
>
> [see css pseudoclass :hover](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

greetings timotheus

Answer (score 0):

Using pure CSS you can achieve the same.

```
 .nav li ul{display:none;}
 .nav li:hover ul{display:block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/80cfd39u/3/)

Comment: I try your code, it's working but, its now showing the submenu. it's all blank

Comment: It's working on mouse over but .It's hide my sub menu.

Answer (score 0):

### Your selector is wrong

You are selecting

```
#nav
```

this selects elements with `id="nav"`

try using

```
#sidebar > .nav
```

To select elements with `class="nav"` as you have (but only direct children of the sidebar).

### Alternatively, use CSS

Something like this.

```
ul.nav li ul {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 500ms;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can achieve it with CSS, but if you want to make your javascript to work:

```
$('#sidebar > .nav > li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.nav').show(500);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.nav').hide(500);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/6v90csv4/)

Comment: This one is working also, same with the CSS example of @Suresh Ponnukalai  but why it's hiding my submenu?

Comment: Don't you want your submenu to only show when its parent li is hoverd? You want the submenus to be always visible you mean?

Comment: Yes your correct, I want to show my submenu when li parents it hover,  but i dont know whats wrong on my code..   when its hover, it show the submenu but without content..

Comment: Content for the first is "Add account" and "Update user" and so on. Did you check the demo or copied it to yours? If the latter it might be there are some extra code causing it. Otherwise, try to empty the cache or something.

Comment: Yes the content of the parents is empty when mouse is hover, I dont know what causing of error. But how to empty the cache? i'll try

Comment: What browser? `ctrl+shift+r` would probably do the job, if on Chrome try your code in incognito mode. And if the code is run on a server check the source to make sure it's been updated.